# Spring Boot Security not ignoring directory using WebSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to ignore directory using websecurity.ignore. I have the following configuration.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/product_save").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()                  
                .logout()
                    .permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().and()
                    .rememberMe()
                        .key("uniqueAndSecret")
                        .rememberMeCookieName("broman-remember-me")
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24).and()
                    .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web)throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }
}
```

The above configuration doesn't ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
}
```

will ignore all URLs that start with `/static/**` like `http://localhost:8080/static/...`

Spring Boot serves the content of the static folder by default. So if you have some folders or files in the static folder (like static resources related to customers and managers, etc..) you can ignore them one by one:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/customers/**", "/managers/**", "/monitor.html");
}
```

This will ignore:

- `http://localhost:8080/customers/` - and all sub-URLs
- `http://localhost:8080/managers/` - and all sub-URLs
- `http://localhost:8080/monitor.html`

Comment: I understood now. Thank you